# PANDAS to JSON: Changing name of columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
df = pd.concat([a,b,c,d,e], axis=1, sort=False)
```

I want to give column names which I usually do to output to Excel as

```
df.to_excel ("ids.xlsx", index = None, header=['IDs', 'Phases','Versions','Internal Version List','Tests'])
```

But when I do output to JSON, where should I give the header inputs?

```
df.to_json ('Export_DataFrame.json', orient='table')
```

Comment: set the names beforehand `df.columns = ['IDs', 'Phases','Versions','Internal Version List','Tests']`, then `df.to_json(....)`

Comment: Can you write this as answer so that I mark it as completed and then it would helpful for others too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the column names beforehand using:

```
df.columns = ['IDs', 'Phases','Versions','Internal Version List','Tests']
```

After you can write the DataFrame to json using:

```
df.to_json ('Export_DataFrame.json', orient='table')
```